# I/O with while and for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, file-io, while-loop

**EDIT:**
I understand now what  my doubt was. I did not understand why the first value (N, the number of values) is not read at the beginning of the while loop and that happened for a VERY simple reason I wasn't aware of at the time.
It happened because it was read before, at the line:

```
 ifile >> n;
```

I thought that in the while loop the file reading would restart from the beginning, instead it starts from the last read line.

Sorry if I haven't been clear before. I hope I am now.

---

I have a file which represents a list of measurements from an experiment, like this:

```
N 
x_1  y_1 ex_1 ey_1
x_2  y_2 ex_2 ey_2
...  ... ...  ...
```

where N is the number of values, and x_1, x_2, ..., the values themselves.
I have to put these values in some arrays so I tried this while loop:

```
int n;
double d,e,f,g;
while (ifile >> d >> e >> f >> g){
x[n]=d;
y[n]=e;
ex[n]=f;
ey[n]=g; 
n++;
}
```

But when I compiled, I saw that the first value (N, which is the number of values) was put into the first array so, because I have to do calculations with the measurements, I cannot use it.
I found out that by using this for loop:

```
int n;
ifile >> n;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
ifile >> x[i];
ifile >> y[i];
ifile >> ex[i];
ifile >> ey[i];
}
```

and printing out the arrays, "N" is not read, and the reading starts from the first value. Why? (x,y,ex,ey are dynamic arrays)

This is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int n;

  ifstream ifile("pendulum.dat");
  if(!ifile){
    cout << "Error in file opening" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  ifile >> n;
  double* x = new double[n];
  double* y = new double[n];
  double* ex= new double[n];
  double* ey= new double[n];
  double* py= new double[n];
  double* pey=new double[n];
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    ifile >> x[i];
    ifile >> y[i];
    ifile >> ex[i];
    ifile >> ey[i];
    py[i]=pow(y[i],2);
    pey[i]=2*(ey[i]/y[i])*pow(y[i],2);
  }

   double S0=0,Sx=0,Sy=0,Sxx=0,Sxy=0;

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    S0 = S0 + 1/pow(pey[i],2);
    Sx = Sx + (x[i]/pow(pey[i],2));
    Sy = Sy + py[i]/pow(pey[i],2);
    Sxx = Sxx + pow(x[i],2)/pow(pey[i],2);
    Sxy = Sxy + (x[i]*py[i])/pow(pey[i],2);
  }

 double a,b,ea,eb;
 a=((Sxy*S0)-(Sx*Sy))/((Sxx*S0)-(Sx*Sx));
 ea=sqrt((S0)/((Sxx*S0)-(Sx*Sx))); 
 b=((Sy*Sxx)-(Sx*Sxy))/((Sxx*S0)-(Sx*Sx)); 
 eb=sqrt((Sxx)/((Sxx*S0)-(Sx*Sx))); 

 cout <<"Value of a is "<< a<<" +- "<<ea<< endl;
 cout <<"Value of b is "<< b<<" +- "<<eb<< endl;


  double g,eg;
  double k=4*pow(M_PI,2);
  g=k/a;
  eg=k*ea;
  cout<<"Value of g is "<<g<<" +- "<<eg<< endl;


  ifile.close();
  return 0;  
  }
```

Comment: I think this line should be added before for-loop. `ifile >> n`

Comment: I forgot to copy that (and  `int n;`) in the question, but they are in the code

Comment: did your code work? If not, please try opening the file with `ios::binary`!

Comment: It always worked; I did not understand why though. Now I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted

```
int n;
ifile >> n;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    ifile >> x[i];
    ifile >> y[i];
    ifile >> ex[i];
    ifile >> ey[i];
}
```

maybe?

Comment: I guess you are right!

Comment: @kiner_shah Yeah, it's pure guesswork here ;)

Comment: I forgot to copy those two lines in the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edited the question, look if it's correct now ;)

Comment: @LorenzoBergamaschi Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the behavior you describe please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried, please tell me if and what do I need to improve

Comment: @LorenzoBergamaschi Go and read the link again. Provide your exact input, provide a minimal but compilable code, that can be copied to e.g. a online IDE and runs out of the box: [not this](http://ideone.com/PSCjkj).

Comment: I would have to send you the file

Comment: @LorenzoBergamaschi _"I would have to send you the file"_ No, please refrain doing so.

Comment: @kiner_shah I finally understand the problem. It was obvious you probably took for granted that I knew it